# animation perspective issue when using 'a' tag

Tags: html, css, animation

Here is the jfiddle that demonstrates my issue -

https://jsfiddle.net/k57qnhwb/

Essentially, I have a card doing a full 360 spin, but I need the spin to have perspective to it instead of just being a flat straight-on rotation.

When I remove the 'a' tag from my code, the perspective works... but I need the 'a' tag, and I need the perspective to work too... I can't figure out why my 'a' tag is breaking the perspective?

```css
body {
  background: black !important;
}

#horizontalstorecontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.store-scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.cardlast {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 50.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation-name: storeslide;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.cardlast img {
  height: 100%;
}

.productwrapper {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

.animationwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -o-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.front {
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.back {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: love 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: love 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: love 5s infinite;
  animation: love 5s infinite;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

@-webkit-keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes swag {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes swag {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swag {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontalstorecontainer">
  <div class="store-scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="cardlast">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <div class="animationwrapper">
          <a href="/thermal-playing-cards-by-missing">
            <img src="https://www.missingnewyork.com/images/thermal-playing-cards-by-missing.png" alt="." class="back" />
            <img src="https://www.missingnewyork.com/images/ace-of-spades-from-thermal-playing-cards-by-missing.png" alt="." class="front" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming it's just some silly syntax error or something, but I can't find it. And to clarify, here is a jsfiddle where the perspective works correct - https://jsfiddle.net/Lf94vkhn/. Please note that during the rotation there is actually perspective, as opposed to it just being flat when the 'a' tag is present.

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to express, because it shows the same thing no matter if I add a `<a>` tag

Comment: No, if the <a> tag is *removed*, not added, then the perspective doessss work. Here is a fiddle where the perspective does work - https://jsfiddle.net/Lf94vkhn/. I need the perspective to work, even when the <a> tag is present.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Incidentally, I see the problem with a div or a span instead of the a. (Tested on IOS/iPad Safari and Windows 10  Edge.)

Comment: I'm using chrome, can't get the perspective to work correctly when the a tag is present in any other browsers either... but I can get the perspective to work perfectly fine in chrome/safari when the a tag is not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs whether the 'inserted' element is an a (anchor) or div or span [or maybe, anything].

I don't have a complete explanation because of not understanding the perspective property in its entirety, but one way round this is to remove the wrapper div and make the a (anchor) element have the perspective as in this snippet:

```css
body {
  background: black !important;
}

#horizontalstorecontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.store-scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.cardlast {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 50.6%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation-name: storeslide;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.cardlast img {
  height: 100%;
}

.productwrapper {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

.animationwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.4px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -o-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.front {
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: swag 5s infinite;
  animation: swag 5s infinite;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.back {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: love 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: love 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: love 5s infinite;
  animation: love 5s infinite;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

@-webkit-keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes love {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes swag {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes swag {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swag {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontalstorecontainer">
  <div class="store-scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="cardlast">
      <div class="productwrapper">
        <a href="/thermal-playing-cards-by-missing" class="animationwrapper">
          <img src="https://www.missingnewyork.com/images/thermal-playing-cards-by-missing.png" alt="." class="back" />
          <img src="https://www.missingnewyork.com/images/ace-of-spades-from-thermal-playing-cards-by-missing.png" alt="." class="front" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately when I apply this method to the website, it breaks other parts of the site that I need to work as they currently do... is there any way to use this same method without removing the animationwrapper class that wraps the images and the link?

Comment: How do you mean, it breaks other parts of the site? What happens? And are other elements using the same class?

Comment: Nevermind! My apologies... I had entered your solution code incorrectly. Your workaround appears to work perfectly. I've just now accepted it as the answer. Thank you so much for your help!